# concat imported data frames with missing data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I don't understand why `pd.concat(list, ignore_index=True)` changes the dtype from 'float' to 'object'...

I have two data frames with imported data:

```
   df_1            df_2

    A   B           A   B     
0   5   7       0   6   8     
1   NaN 1       1   3   5
2   2   9       2   9   1
```

Both of these are `dtypes: float64(2)`

With `pd.concat(list, ignore_index=True)` I do get the desired combined data frame:

```
   df

    A   B               
0   5   7       
1   NaN 1       
2   2   9   
3   6   8
4   3   5
5   9   1
```

...but the types have changed to `dtypes: float64(1), object(1)`

Backstory:
I imported some data from files into separate pandas data frames. Some of the files have missing values, but (if I'm not mistaken) NaNs are treated as float. All the separate data frames (even the ones with missing data) are float (see above), but when I use `pd.concat` to combine them, they change to objects.

I'm guessing it's because of the missing data, but I don't understand why or how to fix it... (I actually need the holes in the data, so I can't just fill in zeros)

Maybe someone can explain this to me...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Because at least one DataFrame has column filled by strings, so after `concat` get mixed `column` - numbers with strings and `dtype=object`. Do you need convert all columns to numbers? Or only some columns to numbers?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After what you said, I searched all my files for strings and finally found the problem: in one of the files, missing values had a single space instead of no value at all. That's the 'string' that made the whole column convert to 'string'.